# Keeping an account logged in an Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-signin

How to keep a account logged in an Android app while using the Google sign in or your own sign in. How to implement it in Android studio, using java.

Comment: You should use firebase google-signin. It won't signout unless you do. Please refer to docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: Can we do without using firebase. I just want to do without firebase.

Comment: If you don't want to use firebase. Here is google-signin api for android. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: Maintain your own session flag once user is logged in first time and save user credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save session Token from backend to 'shared preference'.
And when your app call the api, you should get token from 'shared preference' and then send back token to backend